# How to copy file from one Channel to another using Jsch?

Tags: java, jsch

```
    ChannelSftp sftpFrom = ...........;
    ChannelSftp sftpTo = ............;
```

I'm using `BufferedReader` to read file from the first channel and then writing it line by line to the second channel. Is there any better way of copying file from one channel to another?

Is there any copy paste operation?

Comment: The accepted answer is yet another workaround no better than what i already have. It's a lot of "code yourself" effort

Comment: No actually that answer is better than my approach. apologies